# Why is this Python 2.7 code generating excessive labels?

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I'm working with Python 2.7 using idle.

I have a getVar Button, to get whatever text is in Entry
and put it in myEmpty Label, using a btnWork function. I only want one myEmpty Label.

However, in the following code if I put myEmpty Label in the function, I get labels everytime I click the button. This is not what I want.

```
from Tkinter import *

myGui=Tk()
myGui.geometry("200x100")
myGui.title("basicGUI")
myGui.configure(bg="gray")

entryVar = StringVar()
entryVar.set("")

entry = Entry(textvariable=entryVar, width=10)
entry.pack()

eV = StringVar()
def btnWork():
    global eV
    eV = StringVar()

myBtn=Button(text="getVar", command=btnWork)
myBtn.pack()

myEmpty = Label(textvariable=eV, width=10)
myEmpty.pack()

mainloop()
```

How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click the button you need to get the information with *.get()* then update the label

```
from Tkinter import *

myGui=Tk()
myGui.geometry("200x100")
myGui.title("basicGUI")
myGui.configure(bg="gray")

eV=''

entry = Entry(width=10)
entry.pack()

def btnWork():
    eV = entry.get()
    myEmpty.config(text=eV)

myBtn=Button(text="getVar", command=btnWork)
myBtn.pack()

myEmpty = Label(text=eV, width=10)
myEmpty.pack()

myGui.mainloop()
```

Comment: Wow such an exacting answer that works wonderful. I never would have thought of using `code`myEmpty.config(text=ev).`code` I had it working with my enter key or getting another label when the button was clicked. I got so frustrated! Your code help is perfect. Thanks Tom